# Can I run Ubuntu 13.04 on a Benq Joybook A52?

Tags: drivers, ati, compatibility

Specs:

• CPU: Intel Core Duo T2130 1.86GHz
• RAM: 896MB
• HDD: 100GB
• Graphics hardware: ATI Radeon Xpress 200M

I am new to Ubuntu. Do I need to take care of drivers?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) fglrx driver for ATI Radeon Xpress 200M from Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Thx a lot bro :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The minimum requirements for Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit are:

> 1 GHz Pentium 4 Processor
>
> 512 MB of RAM
>
> 5 GB HDD Space (Minimum)
>
> DVD Drive or an USB port

You don't need to care about drivers for the beginning. Maybe, in the future, you will be interested about this post: [Shall I install ATI drivers, or keep the open source ones for now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78494/shall-i-install-ati-drivers-or-keep-the-open-source-ones-for-now?rq=1)